# How to get access token using credential in java code

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I have to get the access token using credential so that I tried following code

Here is the code:

```
OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
         OAuthClientRequest request =
                    OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
                            .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                            .setClientId("My client id")
                            .setClientSecret("My client secret")
                            .buildQueryMessage();
          String token = client.accessToken(request, OAuth.HttpMethod.POST, OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class).getAccessToken();
```

But I got following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" OAuthProblemException{error='unsupported_response_type', description='Invalid response! Response body is not application/json encoded', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:63)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.setBody(OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.java:76)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:92)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:101)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:60)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:120)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponseFactory.createCustomResponse(OAuthClientResponseFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:111)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
    at org.example.google.accesstoken.main(accesstoken.java:42)
```

Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which api exactly are you trying to connect to?

Comment: I want to use google api to get the profile of the user.

Comment: Do you want signin or just oauth?

Comment: No ,I just want oauth

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at the [People api quickstart for java](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java)

If you have any issues with it let me know I know a lot of the samples are getting updated due to a deprecation in the library.

This sample uses the connections endpoint your probably going to want to change it to the [People get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) method

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.PeopleService;
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.PeopleServiceScopes;
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.model.ListConnectionsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.model.Name;
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.model.Person;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class PeopleQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google People API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(PeopleServiceScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = PeopleQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        PeopleService service = new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Request 10 connections.
        ListConnectionsResponse response = service.people().connections()
                .list("people/me")
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
                .execute();

        // Print display name of connections if available.
        List<Person> connections = response.getConnections();
        if (connections != null && connections.size() > 0) {
            for (Person person : connections) {
                List<Name> names = person.getNames();
                if (names != null && names.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Name: " + person.getNames().get(0)
                            .getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No names available for connection.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No connections found.");
        }
    }
}
```